# I can't put a ArrayList with a bundle from a fragment into another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, bundle

I want to use an ArrayList with my own Data type in another fragment, I test it with a bundle and put the list with the putParcelableArrayList Method but it did not work.

Any ideas why, or a better suggestion?

Fragment 1:

```
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();

arguments.putParcelableArrayList("BESTAND", (ArrayList<Bestand>) palBestand);
```

Fragment 2:

```
ArrayList<Bestand> bestandsliste = (ArrayList<Bestand>) getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("BESTAND");
```

Comment: U need to parcelize you modal class e.g Bestand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here's is Example of Parcelable class

```
public class Student implements Parcelable{
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private String grade;

        // Constructor
        public Student(String id, String name, String grade){
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.grade = grade;
       }
       // Getter and setter methods
       .........
       .........

       // Parcelling part
       public Student(Parcel in){
           String[] data = new String[3];

           in.readStringArray(data);
           // the order needs to be the same as in writeToParcel() method
           this.id = data[0];
           this.name = data[1];
           this.grade = data[2];
       }

       @Оverride
       public int describeContents(){
           return 0;
       }

       @Override
       public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
           dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {this.id,
                                               this.name,
                                               this.grade});
       }
       public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
           public Student createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
               return new Student(in); 
           }

           public Student[] newArray(int size) {
               return new Student[size];
           }
       };
   }
```